# How to prove $\frac{a}{b}=\frac{c-e}{d-f}$ from $\frac{a}{b}=\frac{c}{d}=\frac{e}{f}$?

Tags: algebra-precalculus, solution-verification, ratio

$$\frac{a}{b}=\frac{c-e}{d-f}\ \text{from}\ \frac{a}{b}=\frac{c}{d}=\frac{e}{f}$$

I thought this was [componendo-dividendo](https://brilliant.org/wiki/componendo-and-dividendo/), but it's not. This is something I've never seen before. I tried to prove it by subtracting $1$ from both sides, didn't work. No path seems to work. I found this in my book, but they didn't provide any justification. They just used it. How can I prove this?

Comment: We can write $a=bt,c=dt, e=ft$ for some $t$. Now compute $\frac {c-e} {d-f}$

Comment: … assuming of course that $d\ne f$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Given that
$$
{a \over b} = {c \over d} = {e \over f} = k \ \ \ (\mbox{say}) \tag{1}
$$

Then we have
$$
a = b k, \ \ c = d k, \ \ e = f k \tag{2}
$$

Note that
$$
c - e = (d - f) k
$$

Thus,
$$
{c - e \over d - f} = k \tag{3}
$$

From (1) and (3), we conclude that
$$
{a \over b} = {c - e \over d - f}
$$